# Rewrite propositions with equivalence.

Tags: propositional-calculus

> Rewrite these propositions wih equivalence:
>
> $a:(b \, \lor \, c) \Rightarrow  (\lnot b \, \lor \, \lnot c)$
>
> $b: (\lnot c \, \lor \, q) \Rightarrow r$
>
> $c: a \Rightarrow (\lnot q \, \land \lnot r)$

I got statements which I have to write in the form of equivalence. I translate the statements into the formulas above, but I don't know how can I make equivalence from these formulas.

I tried to substitute $a$ and $b$ to proposition $c$ but it didn't lead to anywhere.

We have implication above and we know that equivalence is: both $p \Rightarrow q$ and $q \Rightarrow p$ but I am not really sure how can I change it into equivalence.

Comment: No, you are being asked to *use* equivalences to rewrite the statements.  What standard equivalences do you know?

Comment: I know only one equivalence ... What do you mean by standard equivalences?

Comment: Your text should have a [table of logical equivalences](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf) or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, I try to do this.